# Vector by referece in constructor: uninitialized reference

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, pass-by-reference

Uses of vector using namespace is wrong. Might be a typo. Please change as follows.
Use std::vector
I have to following code:

```
class MyClass{

private:

std::vector<float>& myvector;

public:

MyClass(int k,std::vector<float>& vector){

(...)

this->myvector=vector;

(...)

}
```

I create a MyClass object like this:

```
(...)

std::vector<float> vector;
vector.reserve(k);

(...)

MyClass A= MyClass(k,vector);

(...)
```

An error pops out telling me MyVector is an uninitialized reference. I just want MyClass to store some data in MyVector and return it. Should I use pointers instead?.

Thanks

Comment: In this code, `myvector` isn't a reference at all. Are you sure you posted the correct code? Or can you show the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Could you please post the exact code, because here there is also a syntax error at std:vector<float>

Comment: Fixed the typos, thank you. The error message is:error: uninitialized reference member ‘MyClass::myvector’ [-fpermissive]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [constructor initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
MyClass(int k, std::vector<float>& v)
    : myvector(v)
{
    (...)
}
```

Also don't use the name of a type as the name of a variable/parameter.

This great explanation from [user3159253](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3159253/user3159253)

> members of the class are initialized before constructor body. So if
>   you don't initialize them explicitly, they're initialized with their
>   respective default constructors. This is often Ok for most datatypes
>   (although they would be initialized twice, once with default
>   constructor and the second time in the body), but not with references
>   which don't have default constructors at all

Comment: Some explanations: members of the class are initialized _before_ constructor body. So if you don't initialize them explicitly, they're initialized with their respective default constructors. This is often Ok for most datatypes (although they would be initialized twice, once with default constructor and the second time in the body), but not with references which don't have default constructors at all.